# Download files from portal

Tags: php, linux, web

Some log files are saved in cloud server and it is placed in another load balancer portal to download it. If I browse the load balancer URL we can see the files to be downloaded. When I click this file its get being downloaded. How this file can be downloaded from Linux commands / php scripts

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux terminal using wget command to download file from specific url.
And using php script to download file, you can use file_get_content() and file_put_content() to download file.
I hope this answer helpful to you.